# Get latest revision from Visual Studio Online through code - TF30063

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to create an automatic *"get latest"*-routine from our Visual Studio Online repository.

However, I have tried a number of examples but they all return:
`TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://ourPath.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/`

I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005274/get-latest-from-visual-studio-online-using-command-line-passing-login-credentia) console app, but it still returns the same error.

I can login through the browser using credentials.
I am running out of ideas on how to connect and get the latest code.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you can log in through the browser using those credentials, then they are not the alternate credentials that should be used in the answer to [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005274/get-latest-from-visual-studio-online-using-command-line-passing-login-credentia).

The credentials you typed in the browser is your Microsoft Account (formerly known as your Live ID).  This is a shiny browser-based authentication experience that is incompatible with the `/login` flag to `tf.exe`.

Instead, you need to [set up alternate credentials for your account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx).  However, this does not enable you to use `tf.exe`, as it does not support them.  You will need to use either:

- The cross-platform TFS command-line client ([Team Explorer Everywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661))
- Your own program that provides these credentials (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005274/get-latest-from-visual-studio-online-using-command-line-passing-login-credentia))