# Cruise control to Visual Studio Online, TF30063: You are not authorized

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net, azure-devops

I am trying to configure Cruise control 1.8.5 to connect to Visual Studio Online to get the source to build and run tests, however whatever I do I always get the error 'TF30063: You are not authorized'

I have copied over tf.exe and required DLLs to the build machine as per one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client) (I would rather not install VS2013 on the build machine if possible, this is just a proof of concept at this point).

I have enabled alternative credentials as per [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-eclipse-projects-vs.aspx)

This is part of the cc.net config - everything in square brackets has been double checked:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vsts">
  <server>https://[account-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection</server>
  <project>$/[proj-name]</project>
  <username>[alt-credential-username]</username>
  <password>[alt-credential-password]</password>
  <executable>[path-to-tf.exe]</executable>
  <workspace>[workspace-name]</workspace>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
  <force>true</force>
  <deleteWorkspace>true</deleteWorkspace>
</sourcecontrol>
```

I have tried my normal credentials, the alternative credentials, and even ##LIVEID##[alt-credential-username] as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365220/connect-teamcity-to-visual-studio-online)

I always get:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://[account-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

Note that I *am* able to connect manually from the build machine, e.g. running the following authenticates successfully and displays the expected directories under source control:

```
tf.exe dir /folders /server:https://[account-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection "$/[proj-name]" /login:[alt-credential-username],[alt-credential-password]
```

(this works from both admin and non-admin cmd)

I also tried to run [this](http://nakedalm.com/getting-service-account-vso-tfs-service-credential-viewer/) to get a 'service account' however it crashes for me on Windows 7 x64

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233268/get-latest-revision-from-visual-studio-online-through-code-tf30063) however as I can manually connect using cmd/tf.exe I am assuming that tf.exe now does support alternative credentials...

I will probably try Team Explorer Everywhere 2013 tomorrow, although I'd rather avoid this due to it being Java based which I have no problem with apart from it's just another dependency / step in the setup.

Any tips/suggestions appreciated, as I'm out of ideas at this point!

**UPDATE:**
Using fiddler as suggested shows the following

tf.exe get from the command line is sending two requests:

1)

```
https://icb.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v5.0/repository.asmx
```

soap body:

```
ReconcileLocalWorkspace [ xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/VersionControl/ClientServices/03 ]
```

with values for workspaceName, ownerName, pendingChangeSignature and maxClientPathLength

2)

```
https://icb.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/VersionControl/v5.0/repository.asmx
```

soap body:

```
Get [ xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/VersionControl/ClientServices/03 ]
```

with values for workspaceName, ownerName, requests, maxResults and maxClientPathLength

However CC is sending this request twice:

```
https://icb.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx
```

soap body:

```
GetRegistrationEntries [ xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Registration/03 ]
```

with toolId=vstfs

Comment: Interesting!  Could you capture a fiddler trace and see what the difference is between what your command-line `tf` is doing versus CruiseControl's?  Can you log the exact command executed by the CruiseControl.NET plugin?

Comment: I realised while playing around that it would make more sense to try a command line (manual) get, and it appears I need to create a workspace first, which I did and am able to get latest. However fiddler shows different requests than what CC is making. I have updated above.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Run the cruise control .net service as the same user you used to create the workspace (not the local system account).

Details:
I ended up getting the cruise control .net source, and attaching a debugger to see exactly what tf command was generating the error.

The process info that was failing:

```
Executable = "...tf.exe"
args = {dir /folders /server:https://[account-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection "$/[proj-name]" /login:[alt-credential-username],[alt-credential-password]}
workingDirectory = "[valid-working-dir]"
```

Running this command manually worked fine - which led me to check the cc service properties, which were set to log on as Local System Account. I updated this to log on as the same (Windows) user that I used to create the workspace and this fixed the problem.

I can only assume that tf.exe is doing something clever with accounts/credentials or maybe it's just that workspaces are tied to particular windows logons?

Thanks to Edward for suggesting I fiddle with fiddler.

Comment: Yep.  Another place I've seen this is SVN and accepting certificates.  I had to login to the CI machine...under the account that ran the CC.Net-Service.  And had to manually run from the commandline a svn list (or whatever) that would prompt for (p) permenant(ly) accepting.  Then CC.NET Service ran svn.exe fine and dandy.