# Trouble getting CruseControl.net v1.85 service to authenticate against TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

I have been going over similar threads concerning TFS and CCnet, dealing with connection/authentication issues.  The most recent one I came across was this
[Cruise control to Visual Studio Online, TF30063: You are not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607233/cruise-control-to-visual-studio-online-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized)

In the above, it was mentioned by @Nick that setting the service logon account to the same username as the TFS account that created the workspace, lets things start working.  Well, ok, but what if the TFS server is on different (and untrusted) domain?

I can log in via team explorer & visual studio etc, just not CCnet.

Anyone run into this type of situation?

Comment: Is team explorer (VS) installed on the same machine as CCnet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one shadow account, account with the same user name and password, to connect to TFS from an untrusted domain.