# Get Latest Version using command-line from VSO?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am looking for a simple way to get the latest version of source code from Visual Studio Online through automation (usually command line).

I cannot seem to authenticate to VSO with the credentials I use to logon to the website with the TF or TEE command line.  I have also searched and found a [TFSGet C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005274/get-latest-from-visual-studio-online-using-command-line-passing-login-credentia) that has authentication failure.

When I use the regular TF.EXE it cannot understand my workspace.  Credentials are cached in Source Control Explorer and Workspace is mapped.

When I use the TEE CLC TF.CMD it cannot authenticate using the user@domain.com and password I use to sign on to the Visual Studio Online web site.

When I use the TFSGet C# program I get TFS Authenticaton Failed.

I read something about alternate credentials, but am completely confused because to set that up I need website address and callback URL.  I've never set up a website and URL for a command-line application before.

What I really want is a KISS principle SFTP or secure WGET access to the latest version of my source code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you need to enable alternate credentials. You were looking in the wrong place to set it up, though. It looks like you were trying to use a service hook.

Just follows steps 1 and 2 in the [VSO OAuth documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview): Click on your user name, go to your user profile, then click on the "Credentials" tab and click on "Enable alternate credentials".